# Laravel multiple ajax request

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

One of my pages in the application triggers a lot of AJAX requests. After a while, I even got a 401 error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide more details about the problem. Logs, code, and examples are all helpful.

Comment: function updatePosition(pos,id_command,route_id=-1) { var url = 'updatePosition'; $.ajax({ method: 'get', url: url, data:{position:pos,id_command:id_command}, success: function(resp){ console.log('ok'); }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert('Error.'); } }); } this js function is called every 10 seconds

Comment: After how many attempts are you receiving the the 401 error? Also, can you provide the thrownError parameter that is provided by the error function?

Comment: http://vv_test/open_route/updatePosition?position=10&id_command=18910 401 (Unauthorized)